# How to return angularFire $on value in angular services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have following code in a controller. This code get the current user's task list.
I want to pack this into a angular service so I can call this easily whenever I want in any controller. example `Task.getList()`

**In Controller**

```
$scope.tasks = {};

$firebaseSimpleLogin(instance).$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) { 
 $firebase(instance).$child('users/' + user.uid + '/tasks/incomplete').$on('child_added', function(taskId) {
  $scope.tasks[taskId.snapshot.name] = $firebase(instance).$child('todos/' + taskId.snapshot.name);
 });
});
```

but I facing a problem here. When I call it in controller. it always returns `undefined`

**In services**

```
getList: function() {
 $firebaseSimpleLogin(instance).$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) { 
  $firebase(instance).$child('users/' + user.uid + '/tasks/incomplete').$on('child_added', function(taskId) {
   return $firebase(instance).$child('todos/' + taskId.snapshot.name);
  });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this problem by breaking things down into smaller pieces. You're trying to return from an inner callback, which is really tricky to deal with. Rather than trying to get everything all loaded in at once, we can separate out these responsibilities.

A nice way of handling this is to separate out the auth code ($getCurrentUser), and the task code (getList).

Here's a sample to a Plunker app I wrote. It will load the tasks for each user who logs in.

http://plnkr.co/edit/M0UJmm?p=preview

I have an Auth factory that handles my Auth code.

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, Fb, $rootScope) {
  var simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(Fb);
  return {
    getCurrentUser: function() {
      return simpleLogin.$getCurrentUser();
    },
    // see plunker for the rest
  };
})
```

I also have a **TaskStore** that handles adding, removing, and syncing of my user's tasks. The store takes in a user's id to initialize. It will then know how to grab the tasks listed by the user.

Then in my controller I can use these together to load a user's tasks. Inside of the promise returned by the $getCurrentUser function, the TaskStore with the user's id can get initialized.

This way my TaskStore is re-useable and independent of my Auth code and a bit easier to manage.